why is mvn build not filtering my resources in application.yaml
Pom.xml
<profile>
        <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
        <id>production</id>
        <properties>
            <toto>coucou</toto>
        </properties>
        <build>       
             <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>

application.yaml
vaadin:
  productionMode: ${toto}

Command
 mvn clean package -Pproduction

Result: cat target/classes/application.yaml
vaadin:
   productionMode: ${toto}


Why using a profile to filter? That looks like a spring boot application in such case do not filter the configuration make either application-dev.properties etc. for different environments (or mutli-document yaml files) or even better provide the configuration from outside of your application and do not package it inside your application...

solution is @toto@ in application.yaml
